# Adding read/write permission to access external HD under Catalina

Tags: python, macos, permissions, electron, macos-catalina

I'm working on MAC application contains a command line tool.
The GUI (electron) using sudo prompt to run the command line tool written in Python.
Under Catalina, the app all needed permission to w/r for the protected directories like Desktop with no issue.
Needed permission request were added to plist and it is signed with list of entitlements. 
All works well except accessing external hard drive. Any try to create folder or modifying its properties using chmod command for example return with permission denied.

Just for note, calling same command from terminal ends well with no issue

Any ideas how I can go over it?
How App can request Full disk access?

Comment: can you provide the minimal version of python app in compliance with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: Any file operation on external harddrive path like os.makedirs(path_to_external) will return with permission denied